# display ['name'] inside of a foreach loop coming from another loop

Tags: php

is it possible to use the indexes values inside of a foreach loop that is contained inside a partent for each. Look at the script below and observe that in the child for each I use `echo'<div>' .$product['name'] . '</div>';` When `$product[' name '];`  belongs to the parent for each. is that possible? I am looking to use the index `['name ']` in the child `foreach()`.

```
foreach($tree as $product){

    echo '<div>' . $product['name']. '</div>';

    foreach($product['variery'] as $variety) 

    {
        echo'<div>'. $variery['image'] . '</div>';
        echo'<div>' .$product['name'] . '</div>';

    } // end of child for each

} //end of parent for each
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. If I did then yes it is possible and you got it right. Have actually you run the code? Are there any problems?

Comment: Hey felix yes I meant that, I haven't test it I wanted to make sure before executing

Comment: Well you won't destroy anything so there is no point in not trying before asking. I mean, very often programming is try and error. But imho you should not ask before you tried....  and yes the others things you ask in the comments are also possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you define a variable in a parent loop, then it will retain its value in any child loops, AS LONG AS those child loops do not themselves redefine the variable. As far as your inner loop is concerned, $product is a "local" constant for the life of the loop, so $product['name'] and $product['variery'] will not change until the next iteration of the outer loop.

As a minor performance tip, you do not have to do string concatenation within your echo statements. echo will accept multiple comma-separated values. The following will work exactly the same and not have the overhead of two concatenations:

```
echo '<div>', $product['name'], '</div>'; // notice the commas
```

It's minor, but if this becomes a heavily traveled code path, any cycles saved are a good thing.

Comment: Marc you mean that instead of something like 

value="' . $variety['price'].'_'. $variety['variety']. '_'$product['name'].'" 

I can easely do it by comman-separated values like:

value="', $variety['price'], $variety['variety'], $product['name'],'"

Comment: The value below will go inside the foreach child loop

value="', $variety['price'], $variety['variety'], $product['name'],'"

Comment: No, the comma separation only applies to the echo command. But the rest holds. As long as you don't overwrite the $product variable inside child loops, it will have the same value for all iterations of the child loop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

Even outside of the loop the `$product` is defined (the last value keeps assigned).

**Question from comments: Can I also do this?**

```
value="', $variety['price'], $variety['variety'], $product['name'],'";
```

the above codee would go inside the child loop.

**Answer:**
Yes, but this syntax will lead to error. To use associative array in the double quotes skip the single quotes.

```
value="', $variety[price], $variety[variety], $product[name],'";
```

Or use dots:

```
value="', " . $variety[price] . ", " . $variety[variety] . ", " . $product[name] . ",'";
```

Comment: Can I also do this? 

value="', $variety['price'], $variety['variety'], $product['name'],'" 

the above codee would go inside the child loop.